# What is a good toolkit for developing Blackberry applications?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, mobile

Looking for a toolkit/SDK for general Blackberry development or application toolkits. Anything like an MVC framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that blackberry's OS is Java ME - based, and that there's a decent development kit for them.  I presume you have already [looked over everything here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/)... you can find a lot of information, including the development kit download link. 
Regarding model-view-controller, there's no particular framework to my knowledge, but I don't see why you wouldn't be able to take MVC as an approach in the paradigmatic sense.  Google has resources out there on java developers working with MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've look into their dev site but I was mainly looking for a Struts/Rails/ish framework for Blackberry dev (or J2ME dev in general)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for beyond the standard SDKs, but you could check out Plazmic's Content Developer Kit:

http://www.plazmic.com/en/index.shtml