# IDEs Used for BlackBerry Developement

Tags: netbeans, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, jde

I have installed eclipse JDE  plugin (ie BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.0.0.67.exe) , i  can create a blackberry project only for BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0 . when i see in window ->preferences ->blackberry->installed components of eclipse ony BlackBerry JDE component package 4.5.0 is available, if i want to have multiple JDEs what should be done .Is there are any IDEs other than Eclipse which are used for   BlackBerry Developement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there are component packs on blackberry server available for [download](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp):

- download the Eclipse Software Update for the BlackBerry JDE vX.X Component Pack zip
- in Eclipse go Help -> Software Updates... -> Available Software -> Add Site -> Archive
- open downloaded update and install it

And you can use them all in one Eclipse installation. Just switch them with window ->preferences ->blackberry->installed components as you already know.

Also may be useful:

- [What is the best IDE for development on the BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771705/what-is-the-best-ide-for-development-on-the-blackberry)
- [Blackberry Development Tips, Tricks & Gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640071/blackberry-development-tips-tricks-gotchas)
- [Blackberry Development - Any suggestions on references and tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009910/blackberry-development-any-suggestions-on-references-and-tools)
- [Blackberry SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097634/blackberry-sdk)
- [Configuring Blackberry Eclipse plugin for 4.70 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174540/configuring-blackberry-eclipse-plugin-for-4-70-components)
- [Blackberry development on scripting language ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901287/blackberry-development-on-scripting-language)
- [JDE Eclipse plugin or Blackberry JDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326352/jde-eclipse-plugin-or-blackberry-jde)
- [Blackberry Development in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081841/blackberry-development-in-visual-studio)
- [blackberry development, is it as userfriendly as smartphone dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368514/blackberry-development-is-it-as-userfriendly-as-smartphone-dev)
- [What is a good toolkit for developing Blackberry applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199077/what-is-a-good-toolkit-for-developing-blackberry-applications)
- [Do I have to use J2ME for Blackberry development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290579/do-i-have-to-use-j2me-for-blackberry-development)

Answer (score 2):

I've mainly used NetBeans to develop Blackberry apps.  You can add multiple platforms to NetBeans corresponding to the different JDEs that you are targeting.  The instructions at:

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/55/blackberry.html

while claiming they are for 5.5, work just fine with the latest version of NetBeans as well.  I have not used Eclipse for Blackberry development.